# how to change property of SelectListItem to selected using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a list

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> workingHoursList = new List<SelectListItem>()
{
    new SelectListItem() {Text="08:00:00", Value="08:00:00"},
    new SelectListItem() {Text="09:00:00", Value="09:00:00"},
    new SelectListItem() {Text="10:00:00", Value="10:00:00"},
    new SelectListItem() {Text="11:00:00", Value="11:00:00"},
    new SelectListItem() {Text="12:00:00", Value="12:00:00"},
    new SelectListItem() {Text="13:00:00", Value="13:00:00"},
    new SelectListItem() {Text="14:00:00", Value="14:00:00"},
    new SelectListItem() {Text="15:00:00", Value="15:00:00"}
};
```

and I would like to change the property of the SelectListItem to selected using reflection. How can I do it?

Comment: Well you'd get the type of `SelectListItem`, get the relevant `PropertyInfo` from that, and call `SetValue`, passing in a reference to the item that you want to modify. What have you tried so far, and what went wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by change the property? Do you want to change the property name e.g. Text to Label or the value of a property e.g. Text="15:00:00" to Text="15:30:00"

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful:

```
 public void LoadWorking()
            { 
                List<string> workingHoursList = new List<string>();
                workingHoursList.Add("08:00:00");
                workingHoursList.Add("09:00:00");
                workingHoursList.Add("10:00:00");
                workingHoursList.Add("11:00:00");
                workingHoursList.Add("12:00:00");
                workingHoursList.Add("13:00:00");
                workingHoursList.Add("14:00:00");
                workingHoursList.Add("15:00:00");
                foreach (string s in workingHoursList)
                    listBox1.Items.Add(s);
            }
      private void buttonChanged_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    string h = "", m = "", s = "";
                    if (textBox_Hour.Text == "") h = "00"; else h = textBox_Hour.Text;
                    if (textBox_Minute.Text == "") m = "00"; else m = textBox_Minute.Text;
                    if (textBox_Second.Text == "") s = "00"; else s = textBox_Second.Text;

                    listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex] = 
                        textBox_Hour.Text + ":" + textBox_Minute.Text+":" + textBox_Second.Text;

                }
                else 
                {

                }


        }
//reading
   private void buttonRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null) {
                string selectedTime = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
                string []split = selectedTime.Split(':');

                int i = 0;
                foreach (string sp in split) 
                {
                    if (i == 0) { labelRead.Text = "Hour: " + sp + "\n"; }
                    else if (i == 1) { labelRead.Text += "Minute: " + sp + "\n"; }
                    else if (i == 2) { labelRead.Text += "Second: " + sp + "\n"; }
                    i++;
                }

            }
        }
```